# How to resolve CORS error while using fetch

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html5-canvas, fetch

I am trying to fetch data from metaweather.com API using fetch in javascript but im getting error

I have tried adding https://crossorigin.me before the API URL but it is not working

I am trying to fetch data as taught in the video but it is not working.

here is the snippet of code and error message

please help

```
    fetch("https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/")
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
Error Message:
```

fetch.js:1 GET https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/ 522

(anonymous) @ fetch.js:1

index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

fetch.js:5 TypeError: Failed to fetch

Error Message:

fetch.js:1 GET https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/ 522

(anonymous) @ fetch.js:1

index.html:1 Access to fetch at 'https://crossorigin.me/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

fetch.js:5 TypeError: Failed to fetch

Answer (score 1):

Put the URL behind “https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/” and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The important part in the error message is this

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If the server you request your data from does not include your origin in its header. Then your browser will block loading that data. And there is not much you can do about it.

I read what crossorigin.me is supposed to do, but apperantly it does not set the header on the response. I would never recommend to use a proxy to fetch data from an API. First you rely on the proxy to be up and running (and  crossorin.me already states that it is not intended for production use) and secondly the proxy will probably make all the requests for you, then enrich em with the headers and send them to you. So you should really trust that proxy handling all your data.